# Importing jquery script with module not working. Yeogurt Generator

Tags: jquery, module, yeogurt

I'm not really sure where this question begins or how to ask it. But I'm using a Yeoman generator — Yeogurt— to make a static website. I have made use of their modular feature but am at a loss for how to write my jquery. They have a jquery file for each module created and when I place my code inside it doesn't do anything. I'm not sure what I'm missing to make it functional. The code works fine in the master script file but I want to make use of the modules so save myself on headache of clutter.

My code I used within the module is below. The code I added was between the document ready brackets otherwise everything was generated with the module.

Thanks,
Jon

```
    'use strict';

// Constructor
var Sidebar = function() {
  this.name = 'sidebar';
  console.log('%s module', this.name);

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sidebar-thumb').click(function(){
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('open');
    });
  });

};

module.exports = Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 1):

**The module file**

1st you need to add this underneath the 'use strict'; bit:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

So Yeogurt generates this:

```
'use strict';

export default class moduleName {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'moduleName';
        console.log('%s module', this.name);

        //jQuery won't work yet
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like with jQuery Enabled:

```
'use strict';

import $ from 'jquery';

export default class moduleName {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'moduleName';
        console.log('%s module', this.name);

        //regular jQuery code can now go here
        console.log($('body'));
    }
}
```

**The main.js file**

In order for it to actually be loaded onto the site though you also have to edit the main .js file as well

```
'use strict';

//enables the use of jQuery
import $ from 'jquery';

//imports your javascript module code ready for use
//you need to add this bit manually
import moduleName from '../_modules/moduleName/moduleName';

//initiates jQuery so that it can be used in all your modules
$(() => {

    //initiates moduleName code
    //you need to add this bit as well
    new moduleName();

});
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I haven't used the generator for a bit of time now but I do love it so this will be helpful the next time I find myself making a quick project :)